# How to transform vertical display to horizontal

Tags: html, css

Currently I developing a registration form ... And I wish to include step by step for the user ... Code at the bottom I get from other site and I already modified some css ... however the element are showing in vertical ... What I need is horizontal ... I tried to position but it doesn't work ...

**Currently Display**

[image]

**What I need**

[image]

**In HTML**

```
<div class="steps">
     <div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label >Step 1</label></div>                    
     <div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label>Step 2</label></div>                  
     <div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label >Step 3</label></div>                 
     <div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label>Step 4</label></div>                
     <div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label >Step 5</label></div>
</div>
```

**In CSS**

```
    .steps{

      width: 200px;
      display:inline-block;
      position: relative;
      padding: 1em 2em 1em 3em;

      vertical-align: top;

    }

    label{
      background: #393D40;
      height: 69px;
      line-height: 69px;
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #44494e;
      color: #889199;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 11px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      text-indent: 52px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease
    }

    label:before{
      content:"";
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 2px solid #25292e;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin: 26px 0px 0px 18px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      transition: border 0.7s ease
    }

    label[for=genger]{
      border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    }

    label:hover{
      background: #2B2E30;
      color: #46b7e5
    }

    label:hover:before{
      border: 2px solid #46b7e5;
    }
```

[**Click for JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ybwwro7z/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ybwwro7z/3/

Comment: @chipChocolate.py : using negative margin is not a good practice

Comment: @undefined - I don't think so.

Comment: @undefined - Have a look at this [documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). It clearly says "Negative values are also allowed".

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thx you ... hope can vote your answer and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ybwwro7z/8/)

#### HTML:

```
<div class="steps">
    <div class='genger'>
        <label>Step 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class='genger'>
        <label>Step 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class='genger'>
        <label>Step 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class='genger'>
        <label>Step 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class='genger'>
        <label>Step 5</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.genger {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: -1px;
}
.steps {
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
label {
    background: #393D40;
    height: 69px;
    line-height: 69px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #44494e;
    color: #889199;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-indent: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease
}
label:before {
    content:"";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #25292e;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 26px 0px 0px 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: border 0.7s ease
}
label:hover {
    background: #2B2E30;
    color: #46b7e5
}
label:hover:before {
    border: 2px solid #46b7e5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ybwwro7z/4/)

check the demo, i have added in css

```
.steps {
width: 100%;
margin: 20px;
vertical-align: top;

}
.genger {float: left;width: 150px; }
```

Comment: if float left it will stuck on left ... and I cant center, padding or margin

Comment: @TheSmile: do you mean text alignment should be center ?, u can still do it

Answer (score 0):

First i have taken out your .steps width just removed the padding

you had also given your genger div codes as

```
<div  id='genger' name='genger'/><label >Step 1</label></div>
```

you have closed the div before the label had started, I changed it to,

```
<div  class='genger' name='genger'><label >Step 1</label></div>
```

also named your id genger to class

hence here is the final code...

```css
#wrapper{
           width:1200px;
           margin:0 auto
      }

.steps{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /*padding: 1em 2em;*/
    vertical-align: top;
          background:red;
          width:100%;
  }
         .genger{
             width:20%;
             min-width:150px;
             float:left;
          }
  label{
    background: #393D40;
    height: 69px;
    line-height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #44494e;
    color: #889199;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-indent: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease
  }

  label:before{
    content:"";
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 2px solid #25292e;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 26px 0px 0px 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: border 0.7s ease
  }

  label[for=genger]{
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  }

  label:hover{
    background: #2B2E30;
    color: #46b7e5
  }

  label:hover:before{
    border: 2px solid #46b7e5;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div class="steps">
      <div  class='genger' name='genger'><label >Step 1</label></div>                    
      <div  class='genger' name='genger'><label>Step 2</label></div>                  
      <div  class='genger' name='genger'><label >Step 3</label></div>                 
      <div  class='genger' name='genger'><label>Step 4</label></div>                
      <div  class='genger' name='genger'><label >Step 5</label></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Hope this helps.

P.S : you can center this menu as well . just wrap it inside a bigger div and give margin: 0 auto

**EDIT::** If you want to be more flexible in your widths, you can add width:100% in the steps class and width 20% in genger class. **See updated code snippet now**